# Editing data from database in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm writing code in ASP.NET but it's not a language related question. Every time when I write a web application and I display some data from database using razor view I have this problem. For example I have simple table with Id and Name in my database. I want to display a table with Names using  EditorFor fields. User can edit all the data and save it. So I use row Id as EditorFor Id, read input values in javascript method, use WebMethod to pass them to Controller and save changes to database. But in this case I can change EditorFor Id in Firebug and pass changes with wrong ids. What's the way to edit data in that case? I don't want to click edit link and redirect user to edit page when he can edit one row. I have 5 rows in database with Names and I want to edit all of them at once.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking about. It's not a situation when a user can not modify data. Let's say I have table with names: dog (id = 1), cat (id = 2), frog (id = 3). User change Frog to Fox but he also changes id from 3 to 2 in Firebug. So when he saves data Cat is changes to Fox because it has id = 2. How to avoid this?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking.  In the question you're talking about a user editing the wrong record, then at the end you ask how to edit multiple records, then in your comment you again ask how to prevent someone from editing the wrong record.  To answer your comment... To prevent the user from editing a record they're not allowed to edit you check the user's permissions before performing the edit.  *Always* check the user's permissions.  *Never* implicitly trust the data coming from the client.

Comment: If any user can modify any data, then what's the problem if they modify it by first selecting the data by Id which displays the editor so they can update it, or if they update it by stuffing the data into the url? It sounds like you are using an ajax client-side post instead of submitting the form. This bypasses the MVC protections.

Comment: @KeithPayne: How does AJAX "bypass the MVC protections"?  Any request, whether a page request or AJAX, is accompanied by the user's identity (however the application is tracking that).  Server-side code should check the permissions on that identity on every request.  If you're assuming that a page request is implicitly secure and can't be tampered with then *you* are "bypassing protections".

Comment: @David I'm referring to the Anti-forgery token.

Answer (score 0):

That's some kind of security, and you must add security method in this situation.
One way is to use RBAC method for your security structure. For example:
Create a table and name it user_groups, then create table of users that has and foreign key to user_groups
Then also add the foreign key to your " simple table "(that has id and name) to user_groups, that represent witch user_groups can update the row,
I this that's clear. When someone want to edit a row, you check if that user has permission to change the row or not?
You can search term "Role Base Access Control" in asp mvc,
Also something useful here:
http://www.webdevbros.net/2009/12/16/role-based-access-control-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditEmailTemplate(EmailTemplate_Mst emailTemplate_Mst, string Command, int id = 0)
{
    try
    {
        EmailTemplate_Mst et = _repository.GetEmailById(id);
        if (Command == "Update")
        {
            et.Title = emailTemplate_Mst.Title;
            et.EmailTemplate_Content = emailTemplate_Mst.EmailTemplate_Content;
            et.EmailTemplate_LastModifyBy = Convert.ToInt64(Session["UserId"].ToString());
            et.EmailTemplate_LastModifyDate = DateTime.Now;
            _repository.UpdateEmail(et);
            return RedirectToAction("ViewEmailTemplate");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
    }
    return View(new { id = emailTemplate_Mst.EmailTemplate_Id });
}
```

---

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-insert-update-and-delete-application-in-mvc-4-using/